# Windows "format disk" and "erase disk" missing for CD drive

Tags: windows, compact-disc

I need to format a cd disk, when I right click my cd drive the disk format is missing, so is the erase disk, how can I reinstate these items. thank you

Comment: Can you tell us what kind of drive, and what kind of disk are involved?

Comment: O.K the problem I have is, that in My Computer, I have an icon with c.c

Comment: O.K the problem I have is, that in My Computer, I have an icon with c.d drive under it, when I right click, on the dropdown I have several options, they used to include options to ERASE DISK, and FORMAT DISK, when I put a re-write disk in the drawer, this option is no longer available, I would like to know how to reinstall these options to the dropdown box. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can only "format"(erase) as CD if it's rewritable. Otherwise you can't erase the CD.

Comment: I have an cd r\w in drive but there is no option for format or erase when r\clicking on cd drive dropdown, I was looking for an answer to get the missing options reinstalled. thank you

Comment: See this: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/erase-cd-dvd#1TC=windows-7

Answer (score 0):

You can actually erase -r +r discs in some burners it simply removes all data but writing over it all, the disc is useless then but it destroys the data.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question (which is about missing menu items).